# Has there been any work done towards running Objective-J code in a node.js process?

Tags: node.js, objective-j

More specifically, I'm looking to serialize plist's from string data within a node.js process and send them in a request.

For example:

```
var data = [CPPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:dict format:CPPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:errorString];
```

Narwhal has a [module](http://narwhaljs.org/available-packages.html) for this . I was just wondering if someone had done the same for node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Your title is a bit confusing, in case you want to load `.plist` files as JavaScript Objects you could take a look at the the [node-plist](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-plist) module.

I tried to install it via npm but one of its dependencies needs some additional stuff in order to compile. You should take a look at the README of [libxmljs](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs) and make sure you got everything that's required installed before installing it via npm.

Comment: @pnitsch OK, then the only way I can imagine getting this to work is writing your own C++ extension which calls the ObjC code and wraps it for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

check out https://bitbucket.org/clbruno/objj-node